# Can I let others update one particular Facebook page via ping.fm?

Tags: facebook

I can update my "personal" Facebook page via Gtalk or Skype using Ping.fm .

Now we created company's Facebook page under **my Facebook login** and I wonder if I can **let others update company's Facebook page** via Skype or gtalk using Ping too. And of course do not let them post to my "personal" Facebook page.

Comment: Ping.fm is no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the login details to your company's page. Logout of your personal page, then add [the facebook network again](http://ping.fm/networks/), with your company page's login credentials. Once that is done, create a group containing only the company's facebook page (example: let the group name be fbwork).

To post to this group prefix `#fbwork` before your status to make it post to this page

Comment: but I still want to be able post personal stuff

Comment: @Radek create another group `fbmine` and to post to that group, enter  `#fbmine I love waffles` to update your status to `I love waffles`

Comment: I know about this option but won't be others able to use `#fbmine` too? I want them to be able to use `#fbwork` only

Comment: I updated the question... `we created company's facebook page under my facebook login` probably it was not so clear

Comment: I doubt it's possible to do what you wish to do. @Radek